# float in the center in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to center several boxes in CSS? Suppose I have a div "**navigation**". Now, the navigation margin is **auto**, that is, it is in the **center**, how would I add lists(`display:inline`) inside navigation that will expand navigation on both sides. I haven't set the width property so the width will be dynamically expanding. Its like `float :center`.

Comment: Can we have some code example on fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `margin:auto` and `width:940px` and you are done. You can change width as per your need. But giving some width is compulsory.

Check this fiddle and tell me if it helped you.
http://jsfiddle.net/JNMZ3/4/

You can change padding of the li elements for more space. And then adjust width of the navigation div to keep it in center.

Comment: alright, Now if I have several boxes inside navigation and I want to align them into center, what should I do?

Comment: What HTML element are your 'boxes' exactly? <li> <span> <div> or <p>

Comment: If you can give me a link to the code it would be of immense help.

Comment: Check the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this? what is fiddle? and where should I check?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
your css replace with

http://jsfiddle.net/JNMZ3/3/

```
.navigation li{
    margin: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    zoom:1;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: .nav>li isnt targetting the list. I have to target the list by writing li{...} why isnt it targetting the list?

Comment: give your source code then i easily give your solutions if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [one](http://jsfiddle.net/N3qmH/4/). 
Use **margin: 0 auto;** will get your element centered most of the time. (Quick note: your element must have a declared width for this to work.)

The **margin: 0 auto;** rule is shorthand for 0 top and bottom margin, and automatic left and right margins. Automatic left and right margins work together to push the element into the center of its container.

The **margin: 0 auto;** setting doesn't work perfectly in every centering situation, but it works in a whole lot of them.

reference: [You Can't Float Center with CSS](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2012/05/you-cant-float-center.html)
 
**HTML**

```
<div class="leftsidebar">a</div>
<div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
<div class="content">c</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftsidebar 
{ 
height: 608px; 
width: 100px; 
background:red; 
float:left; 
} 

.rightsidebar { 
background:blue; 
height: 608px; 
width: 100px; 
float:right; 
} 

.content { 
width: auto; 
margin:0 auto;
background:yellow; 
height:608px; 
}
```